# How to steal source code through clickjacking?

Tags: clickjacking

Is it possible to steal the source code through clickjacking, so that attacker can also steal the CSRF tokens?

This is a demo attack website:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

</div>
<div draggable="true" ondragstart="test();">
<h3>DRAG ME!!</h3>
<script>

function test(){

    var v1 = document.createElement('iframe');
    v1.src = "http://demo.testfire.net/search.aspx?txtSearch="
    v1.setAttribute("style", "opacity:0.5");
    v1.setAttribute("border", "0");
    v1.setAttribute("scrolling", "0");
    v1.setAttribute("id", "pi");

    document.body.appendChild(v1);

    document.getElementById("pi").onload =function(){
        alert(this.responseText);
    }

}

</script>
</html>
```

Now as you can see I am trying to steal the source code with the help of an alert box. But I didn't succeed in that.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not possible to use clickjacking to get cross-origin access to the source code of a web page. This access is restricted by the [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) and clickjacking does not bypass it. This means that, similar to a CSRF attack, you can cause a cross-origin action with clickjacking but you cannot read back the result of this action.

Thanks for Arminius for pointing out in a comment that it was once possible to exfiltrate content using clickjacking by using cross-origin drag and drop. See for example [Clickjacking 2.0 with drag & drop](http://www.h-online.com/security/news/item/Clickjacking-2-0-with-drag-drop-978600.html) or [this bug for Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=605991). This seems to be forbidden in the browsers for a while now, i.e. modern browsers should no longer be affected by this.

Comment: However, at least historically, there have been tricks such as invisible drag-and-drop operations to exfiltrate content from cross-origin frames.

Comment: @Arminius: thanks for the feedback. I've added it to the answer.

Comment: Yeah, Like my code above. But that's the question, How can I? Please see the question above.

Comment: @UtkarshAgrawal: *"How can I?"* - to cite myself: *This seems to be forbidden in the browsers since a while now, i.e. modern browsers should no longer be affected by this.* In other words: you can't.

Comment: Okay, so now we can't steal anything through this. But we can do XSS with it?

Comment: @UtkarshAgrawal: you might maybe use clickjacking to let the user exploit a XSS issue in the page which is only exploitable same-site. See https://www.acunetix.com/blog/articles/clickjacking-blind-xss/